# Proper way to hyperlink a block area with an image and header tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a question that should be simple enough, but yet is very frustrating to deal with. First of all, I'd like to state that I'm attempting to achieve maximum compatibility among browsers, and to hopefully make this HTML5-compliant if possible.

What I'm trying to do is create a block-area link that has both an img and an h3 tag inside of it.

My original attempt a while ago was to do the following:

```
<div class="link-block">
   <a href="#">
      <img>
      <h3>Title</h3>
   </a>
</div>
```

While (to my understanding) it is valid to have a header tag in an anchor tag according to HTML5 specifications, it caused a weird issue when dealing with older versions of Internet Explorer, in that the link was not always clickable. (This issue, however, may have been due to the fact that the site had a slightly different structure)

Now, on the other hand, I thought I'd do a slightly different idea that should achieve the same thing in a more backwards-compatible way, and that was to do something like this:

```
<div class="link-block">
   <a href="#"></a>
   <img>
   <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
```

with the CSS mark up of:

```
.link-block{
   position: relative; 
}
.link-block a{
   width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;
   position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; 
}
```

This works beautifully in all the browsers I tried (Opera, Firefox, Chrome, Safari) -- Except Internet Explorer. I'm trying it with IE10, and it decided that -- whenever you hovered over the area -- the only clickable areas are ones that are not covered by the image or the h3 tag.

Is my second method above not technically valid? I know IE tends to have a lot of issues displaying content properly, but I thought IE10 was supposed to finally fix a lot of their issues.

What would be the proper approach to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

EDIT: I should also note that I have played around with the z-index of the `<a>` tag, as well as the `<h3>` and `<img>` tag; it still gives IE the same issue.

Comment: What is the problem with using just `img` and `h3` inside an `a` element? Please be specific: which browser(s) exhibited which problematic behavior for which specific markup and CSS? Why do you think you need a `div` wrapper, and how does it relate to the issue?

Comment: The issue was in IE when it was in compatibility mode, and made it so that certain areas of the block was not clickable. The surrounding div is just to closer match my code

Comment: Then don’t put IE into compatibility mode. And the original problem is still unclear. Please provide a self-contained example and identify which specific part of which block is not clickable in which version(s) of IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're facing two problems here. Firstly, some older browsers (primarily old IE), rightly or wrongly, would implicitly close all inline elements whenever a block element was encountered. In this case, your first attempt would have been interpreted as:

```
<div class="link-block">
   <a href="#"><img></a>
   <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
```

Which is not useful at all. The solution to this was to use `display:block` on the `A` tag.

The second issue is that some browsers (again, primarily IE), this time mostly wrongly, have assumed that if you place an invisible element over visible elements, that you will want to interact with the visible rather than the invisible. This makes the solution to the first issue redundant, and causes the problems with your second solution.

My suggestion would be to forget the `A` tag altogether, and instead use the onclick event of the parent `DIV`:

```
<div class="link-block" onclick="document.location.href='#';">
    <img>
    <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
```

You could also add `cursor: pointer;` to the `link-block` class to change the cursor, to make it behave like a link.

Comment: Though I'm sure that this method would work, would it not violate the standard structure of a website?
How would that work for crawlers like from Google? I'm just looking to maximize compatibility, and IE is not making it easy

Comment: If you need search engine crawlers to read the link, then put it back in. Use both methods together, and you'll cover the most bases.